# Class variable set by BackgroundWorker not persisting.

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I am brand new to the idea of BackgroundWorkers, so this has me a little perplexed.

So I created a new WPF Application and created a BackgroundWorker and List class variable:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    private List<int> tempList = new List<int>();
    ...
```

Then I use the BackgroundWorker to populate that list: (In the same class btw)

```
    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int j = 1; j <= 100; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                tempList.Add(r.Next(100));
            }
            ...
        }
    }
```

Now here is the part that's getting me...

The code that populates that list seems to be working fine. When I step through its execution, *it behaves as I have intended until the exact moment the code exits the bw_DoWork method.* After that point, **it reverts back to an empty list.** I changed the list to static at one point but nothing changed.

**So why is this List not persisting throughout the programs execution?**

I am(was) almost certain that this is some issue with the list being allocated in different memory regions for each thread, but I simply know far too little about about BackgroundWorker and MultiThreading in general to diagnose it myself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would pass the list in as an object arg or create it in `do_work` as you leave yourself open to cross threading issues currently

Comment: Could you check whether the list also appears as empty within the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler?

Comment: What Douglas said, also is the `RunWorkerEventArgs.Error` return null or an error?

Comment: Check http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

Comment: You should use lock or other synchronization mechanism since a simple list is not thread safe.

Comment: @DGibbs Thanks for your suggestion. I'm not quite sure how to do that yet, but I'll look into that shortly.

Comment: @Douglas I just checked, and it does persist into the RunWorkerCompleted event handeler. Does that mean that it's definitely some sort of threading issue?

Comment: To clarify on what the others are saying: It is fine to write to a list on one thread and then read it on another, provided the two don't overlap. There is a very small chance that the issue is caused by stale values in processor caches, but that would be eliminated if you use proper synchronization mechanisms.

Comment: @StephenMarsh: Are you actually waiting for the background thread to complete executing before attempting to read the list? If so, how?

Comment: @Sayse e.Error is null.

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? I bet you set tempList at another point without realizing it.

Comment: @Douglas At the moment, I am not reading or accessing the list anywhere else in the program. I am only looking at its elements in the debugger.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos [Link to the full code](https://gist.github.com/StephenMarsh/5985022)

Comment: @StephenMarsh: I assume the debugger is, for some reason, seeing a stale state of `tempList`. However, your application won't be reading the list before `bw_RunWorkerCompleted`, so you're fine.

Comment: @StephenMarsh, I can't reproduce your problem. In RunWorkerCompleted the list contains the expected 100K items. Where did you check that the list is empty?

Comment: Technical explanation: The `BackgroundWorker` class implicitly generates memory fences such that the latest value of any data written by `DoWork` is guaranteed to be seen by `RunWorkerCompleted`. However, if you check the state of the list from elsewhere, without proper synchronization, you might get stale values (or, more likely, a data race).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ooooohhhh. I think I see the problem now! The problem was that in my initial versions of this program I *was* reading from the list before it was written (I read from it right after the bw.RunWorkerAsync(); mistakenly thinking that it would be executed only after the RunWorkAsync() has finished). That, coupled with the fact that Visual Studios apparently doesn't show Variables values when you step out of that codes context, even though it still has a value. Thanks

Comment: Why are you creating `tempList` in `MainWindow`? I would have `bw_DoWork` create it and return it in `bw_DoWork.RunWorkerCompleted`.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start using more expensive options such as locking or thread safe collections. Try out Threading Tasks. If they work then you have some kind of a problem with your BackgroundWorker, if they don't then your code touches the list somewhere and you'll have to trace that.. (I just think Tasks are so much easier to work with)

```
private void bw_DoWork()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                 var r = new Random();
                for (int j = 1; j <= 100; j++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                    {
                        tempList.Add(r.Next(100));
                    }
                    //the rest of whaterver you're doing...
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Stephen Marsh like @Douglas said you need to wait until work is finish.

See this:

```
// this execute the DoWork asynchronously.
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
// asynchronously means the next line may be executed
// before the DoWork fill the list. In fact can be executed
// before the DoWork begin.
MessageBox.Show("Without wait: " + tempList.Count.ToString());
```

To correct you can add this line before call `RunWorkerAsync`:

```
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
```

and put this in any place of the MainWindows class.

```
void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Completed: " + tempList.Count.ToString());
}
```

In my tests always the result was:

```
"Without wait: 0"
"Completed: 100000"
```